# What is the function of body ( ) parameter in Tkinter simpledialog?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to customize my `simpledialogbox` in Tkinter in order to fit my text into the box. When I read the document, I did not detail info about it.  How can I do that?

Comment: please provide more information of what you want to do, a [mre] and there also is documentation, if you want more customization of a messagebox, you need to create it yourself

Comment: I am trying to know what is the body parameter in Tkinter/simpledialogbox.  Due to this reason, I don t know how to give example about it.

Comment: The `body()` function is used to create the dialog content above those dialog buttons.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to customize the box, for example, "please provide more information of what you want to do, a minimal reproducible example and there also is documentation, if you want more customization of a messagebox, you need to create it yourself" if I write this text into simple dialogbox as yes/no it will not be seen properly. I assume the body() helps for it because  I did not see other parameters related to my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.simpledialog) may be a bit confusing, but the way to use `body` is this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label
from tkinter.simpledialog import Dialog


class MyDialog(Dialog):
    def __init__(self, master, title=None):
        super().__init__(master, title)

    def body(self, master):
        Label(master, text='some text here').pack()


root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

MyDialog(root, title='some title here')
```

Comment: I tried but I could not make it. Can you show me how can I use it inside a function for resizing my simpledialog box?

Comment: @ugur I think you will need to ask another question about it. Then also provide what you tried (add a [mre] in that question), then you can link it here so I can take a look, otherwise I don't even know what exact issue you are facing, so ask another question, provide a [mre], then link it here